# Android - (Android Studio) - Create similar to TODO, but different COLOR AND NAME?

Tags: android-studio, todo

I found one post that seemed similar, but didn't fully address my question.

As the title suggests:

In Android Studio, how can I create a word/rule (similar to the way `TODO` works), which when typed, changes its color, and formatting?

**Random Example:** When I type `// TEST:`, it turns a bright green that is bold or italic.

**PS**: I don't want this to have anything to do with my `TODO` list.

In fact, I wanted it to do nothing at all, but if I could add it to a new list, that'd be even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Android Studio, click: File > Settings > Editor > TODO > Click the "+" Sign (on right).

Use similar syntax as the `TODO` and `FIXME` rules that are already built-in, like: `\btesting\b.*`

Double-click the left-most Icon to adjust Color-Schemes.